# How can I print data from a URL AP JSON I in my HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I have never worked with the JSON API before, I am trying to print the URL information in my HTML but I don't know how, I am using the following code but I get the following error in chrome

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
 </head>
<body>
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
    <script src="/jquery-3.5.1.js" >
    </script>
    <script>
            $.get('URL')
                .done((data) => {
                    $('results').html(data);
                }) 
                .fail((error) => console.log(error))        
                .always(() => console.log('Done'));        
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It shows me the following error

```
 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'URL' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Comment: `'URL'` needs to be a valid web path to the resource you want

Answer (score 0):

Try opening your file through a webserver(WAMPP, XAMPP, Laragon, etc.) instead of opening it directly. Your code works fine and you'll sure see for you self if you do as advised.

Comment: Ok, yes sir, if it worked, but now I get the next error, what could it be?   

Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
         at (index):12
    (anonymous) @ (index):12

Comment: Your html page can't find a jQuery Lib. You should copy your Query file along with the Html Files to your webserver

Comment: Ok, Ok, I managed to do that, now I get the following error. 

GET http://localhost/net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

I have read a solution, which says to put all files in a static path, on the server with the following line (app.use("/static", express.static('./static/'));) but how do I configure a static path in XAMPP?Is there a way to do this without configuring anything else? I'm from Colombia and I can't find information in Spanish

Comment: You may mark this question as answered, then raise another question to address you other need. In your new question, endeavour to add an appropriate tag, so your question will get the required attention quickly.